# Get IAM users list by java aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Want to get list of all IAM users using sdk aws java.  Class that we are using is AmazonIdentityManagementClient  and method used is listuser(). API doc suggest pass parameter MaxItem and Marker. Whereas method do not recognize the parameter. Can anyone suggest how to do pagination here.

```
    AmazonIdentityManagementClient amazonidentitymanagmentclient = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient();

    ListUsersResult listuserresult = new ListUsersResult();

 try {

       listuserresult=amazonidentitymanagmentclient.listUsers();

       List<User> listuser = new ArrayList<User>();

       listuser = listuserresult.getUsers() //need to pass maxitems,marker here
     }


     } catch (Exception e) {
         return null;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
ListUsersResult listUsers(ListUsersRequest listUsersRequest)
                          throws AmazonServiceException,
                                 AmazonClientException
```

to use the marker feature.
You can set the marker in the  [ListUsersRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/ListUsersRequest.html) . You need to get the marker from the results ( [ListUsersResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/ListUsersResult.html) ) of previous call of the listusers. The ListUsersResult has a method  [getMarker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/ListUsersResult.html#getMarker())  which can be used to get the marker to be used for next call. Then use the object ListUsesrsRequest. set the marker with the value got from getMarker and then call this  [listusers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/AmazonIdentityManagement.html#listUsers(com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.ListUsersRequest)) . Do this in a loop till the isTruncated method in the ListUsersResults indicates there are no more elements to return. If you don't set maxitem, by default it will return 100 items as per documentation. You can set that in your ListUsersRequest to a different value based on how much you want to display in a page.